# gRPC & distributed transaction in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices

We are designing a new RPC-based approach for our back-office services and we are considering the usage of gRPC. Currently we are using a REST method to call our services, but we realize with time to design a nice REST API is a really hard job and when we look to our internal APIs it looks more RPC than REST. Therefore the shift to pure RPC is valid alternative. I'm not talking here about public APIs - they will continue to be REST-based.

Now, when there are a number of microservices that are/can be distributed one has to compensate issues during commands (write interactions, aka HTTP POST, PUT, DELETE).

I'm curious how you would solving the issue? Thank you!

Comment: What issue? Could you please add a descriptive example of specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

distributed transactions should be avoided in microservices. they are very had to implement and will lead to problems. 
try to look at the commander pattern things like eventual consistency and retries.

Below is a helpful article

https://www.grahamlea.com/2016/08/distributed-transactions-microservices-icebergs/